# Cannot assign a value of type 'NSData' to a value of type 'NSUUID?'

Tags: ios, swift, types, watch

I am trying to make my pebble watch load an pebble watch app through swift and am getting an error :

> "Cannot assign a value of type 'NSData' to a value of type 'NSUUID?'"

Here is my code in AppDelegate.swift :

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    let pebble = PBPebbleCentral.defaultCentral()
    pebble.delegate = self

    var uuidBytes = Array<UInt8>(count:16, repeatedValue:0)
    let uuid = NSUUID(UUIDString: "MYUUIDiknow")
    uuid?.getUUIDBytes(&uuidBytes)
    pebble.appUUID = NSData(bytes: &uuidBytes, length: uuidBytes.count)

    watch = pebble.lastConnectedWatch()
    return true }
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Try just assigning `pebble.appUUID = uuid`